# returns the error mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given for steam login

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, steam

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Hey, keep getting this error, not sure why. this is code for steam login, I've seen this error posted a bunch on here but can't seem to find anything specific if you could link previous answers/help would be awesome.

```
foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
 {
 $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE steamid = '$player->steamid'";
 $query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);

$_SESSION['name'] = $player->personaname;
 $_SESSION['steamid'] = $player->steamid;
 $_SESSION['avatar'] = $player->avatar;

if (mysqli_num_rows($query_id) == 0) {
  $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO users_steam (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES  ('$player->personaname', '$player->steamid', '$player->avatar')";
 mysqli_query($db, $sql_steam);
}
 }
```

$db comes from including db.php which has the code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a valid connection object to pass to the `mysqli_query` function. In your case, there are two problems:

1. You close the connection right after you create it - `mysqli_close($link);` in `db.php`
2. The variable name (`$db`) is not the same which you give (`$link`) in `db.php`.

So you have to:

- remove `mysqli_close($link);` from `db.php`
- change `$db` to `$link` on the line `$query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);`

Comment: 3. use parameterized queries.